# Vuex - Computed property based on a modules state does not update on dispatch?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuex

I am exploring the module documentation for Vuex and have been stuck for quite a while now with updating a value within a modules state from the component which uses it. Here is what I have so far:

*app/store/index.js*

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import Counter from './modules/Counter'
Vue.use(Vuex)
export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules: { Counter }
})
```

*app/store/modules/Counter.js*

```
const state = {
  current: 0
}

const mutations = {
  INCREMENT_CURRENT_COUNT (state) {
    state.main++
  }
}

const actions = {
  increment ({ commit }) {
    commit('INCREMENT_CURRENT_COUNT')
  }
}

export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state,
  mutations,
  actions
}
```

*app/components/Test.vue*

```
<template>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <p>{{ count }}</p>
    <button @click="something()">Do something</button>
    <button @click="add()">Add to count</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import { mapState, mapActions } from 'vuex'

  export default {
    computed: mapState({
      count: state => state.Counter.current
    }),
    methods: {
      something () {
        alert('hello')
      },
      ...mapActions('Counter', {
        add: 'increment'
      }),
    }
  }
</script>
```

Essentially, all I am trying to do is increment the `current` value in the `Counter` module when clicking the button in the component which fires the `add()` method, it is what I might expect given the above but what actually happens is nothing.

So no error and the `count` value within the vue component remains at 0.

Any ideas on what what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you replicate this issue on Codesandbox? It'd make it easier to debug and understand it.

Comment: @Phiter Thanks for the input. https://codesandbox.io/s/415j60717 and it works (facepalm). My use case and issue was a little more complicated though as I had explained in a comment on the answer.

Comment: damn I didn't even notice this when i was reading the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change `state.main++` to `state.current++`

```js
const mutations = {
  INCREMENT_CURRENT_COUNT (state) {
    // change state.main -> state.current
    state.current++
  }
}
```

Comment: Godammit I didn't notice that

Comment: Well spotted, thank you! This being said I did spot this when I was making an example on codesandbox. The issue for me specifically is that I was using this in conjuction with electron, specifically `vuex-electron` and did not note the part where it says `you need to create an instance of store in the main process`. Solved my problem with that although I know it was not really included in my simple example (no tags for this package yet).

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't with the click handler or the action, it's in the mutation.
In your mutation `INCREMENT_CURRENT_COUNT` you have this:

```
INCREMENT_CURRENT_COUNT (state) {
    state.main++
}
```

Whilst your state only has a property called `current`.

In order to make it work, change:

```
state.main++
```

To:

```
state.current++
```